# ghostscript converts my pdf to cmyk but not really

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cmyk, srgb

I run this command and the conversion is successful

```sh
    gs \                                                                                                                                      
       -o converted-to-cmky.pdf \
       -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
       -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK \
       -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK \         
       -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK \
       ./original-srgb.pdf
```

But then I run

```
identify -verbose ./converted-to-cmky.pdf
```

And it still reports 'Colorspace: sRGB'. Any idea of what could be causing this?
Thank you.

Comment: Almost certainly this is a problem caused by 'identify' rather than the pdfwrite device. But without seeing either the input or output PDF file it is not possible to tell. I believe that, when given a PDF file, the identify tool renders it to an image, so the colour space it is reporting is the colour space of the rendered image, not the PDF file.

Comment: You might be right! Visually comparing both files, I can appreciate some different colors. Just another question: If I have images inside of the PDF, they will also be converted to the CMYK color space, correct?

Comment: Yes, ColorConversionStrategy converts everything to the specified space. The exception is DeviceN and Separation colours, where the alternate is transformed to the requested space, but the Separation and DeviceN colours remain as such.

Comment: Note: it says "colour space is sRGB", not that you are using RGB. Like the JPEG: is uses (often) sRGB colour space, but they are encoded with YCC colour model). You do not specify any colour space in `gs`, so it keeps sRGB colometry, just it convert to a new model.

Comment: No, that is not the case. The -sColorConversionStrategy does actually direct Ghostscript to convert the colour representation from anything that is not CMYK into a CMYK definition. It is possible for an RGB defintion to be out of gamut in CMYK, in which case the RGB is converted to the nearest CMYK equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick identify is basically lying. It has no idea about individual objects in the PDF file. PDF can easily contain both CMYK and RGB objects, not to mention spot color plates etc., mixed all together.

Use either commercial Adobe Acrobat Pro preflight check to see the actual situation, or open the resulting PDF in Scribus and go to Edit-Colours  and remove unused colours, to see if all colours in the PDF are actually CMYK or not. Probably they will be even though identify will think the PDF being RGB.